# react add/edit user not working simultaneously

Tags: reactjs, redux

We are using React 16.1.1 version along with Redux. 
If already one react forms Add user process is going on , which is taking a bit longer time, application not allowing to add another user again ( if earlier process is not completed ). Save button not getting hit again.

Is it possible to have concerent ( add user events ) multiple user addition one after another even though its taking longer duration

Sample Code below

If AddUser request is taking long time, then application wont allow to add another new user immidiately if we do so.

```js
/* Saga File  ************************************/

export function* watchAddUser() {
  while (true) {
    const action = yield take(CREATE_USER_REQUEST)
    try {
      const response = yield call(userService.addUser, {
        userData: action.payload.userdata
      })
      yield put(addUserSuccess(response))
   
   // Call for User listing service
   const responseForUserList = yield call(userService.index)
    } catch (error) {
      yield put(addUserFailure(error.data))
    }
  }
}
/* Saga File  ************************************/
```

Is it possible to have one saga action is yet processing , still we are initiating same action again.

Ex:
If user "ABC" record  is getting added via addUser  form, this process is taking more than 2 minutes time. Backend java thread is running to complete the process.
Meanwhile we came on user listing page to add new record and and start another user record "xyz" creation, which is not working as first user record call saga process is not completed.

Is it possible to achieve it , like shown in above example assuming "CREATE_USER_REQUEST" process is not completed, so how to make is another user creation working ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We can only help you fix your code problems if you show us a code example. The example should be as short as possible to illustrate the problem. It should also not contain any additional errors other than what you are asking about. For tips about creating a good code example, please read [mcve].

Comment: Please edit and update the question with relevant code

Comment: Please add more details with code examples, so that we can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Found below link to overcome new async call request.
https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/tree/master/docs/api#spawnfn-args

yield spawn(userList, action)
"creates a detached task. A detached task remains independent from its parent and acts like a top-level task. The parent will not wait for detached tasks to terminate before returning and all events which may affect the parent or the detached task are completely independents (error, cancellation)."

It is working now.

Thank you